# Firebase and swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get the information of my database made with Cloud Firestore. What I want is getting the documents or the collections. My code is attached below. It is perfectly connected with the database, however when I run the app, getdocuments is empty. Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

```
self.db.collection("Students").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
}

var db: Firestore!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // [START setup]
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()

        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
    // [END setup]
        db = Firestore.firestore()

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is there actually anything *in* the Students collection (check it with the Firebase console)? Are you authenticated? Is there an error printed? How is self.db initialized?

Comment: Are you not getting any kind of "Error getting documents" message? Double check your xcode console and see.

Comment: There is something in Students collection. I am authenticated, and no error printed. what do you mean with how is initialized? how can I check that?

Comment: I am not getting errors when I run it

Comment: What is self.db as it's not shown in the question. Your code works for me so the issue may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Hey Jay, please find in the question what db is. Thanks

Comment: Your code still works for me. In fact, I copy and pasted it into a project and it retrieved the students from a Students node I created in Firestore. Can you include what your Firestore structure looks like? Also, if you want to get someones attention, include a @persons_name in your comment reply and it will show up in their InBox

Comment: Thank you @Jay How can I add an image to the comments?

Comment: Please add code and structures to the original question, not in comments. Adding them to the question makes them readable, searchable and keeps the data in one place. In general it's preferred to included code and structures as *text* not links or images. However, in this case with Firestore a screenshot of your structure would work since there isn't really export option like there is in Firebase Database.

Comment: Thanks @Jay , I just added the screen shot

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question works for me with the exact structure posted. The only thing that I can see currently is this

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
```

As a shot in the dark, how about about changing your Firestore initialization to the following

```
var db: Firestore!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.db = Firestore.firestore()
    let settings = self.db.settings
    settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
    self.db.settings = settings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put "/Students"

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()       
db.collection("Students").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I put Students as well, and it didn't work. Actually that is what I tried at first

Comment: Please check if you have the correct GoogleService-Info.plist file. Update it if required. This code works for me.

Comment: Put a debug and check if it goes inside getDocuments() and see if you are getting any error

Comment: It doesn't go inside getDocuments() but it doesn't give any error netiher @Yogesh Tandel

Comment: try removing pod Firestore and then reinstalling it.. might work. have worked for me in some other issues

pod 'Firebase/Firestore'